Pasar librería C++ a C#
Estoy intentado pasar una librería de C++ a C#. La tengo hecha pero el programa, sin concretar qué, ya que va con un dongle, me dice que algo no es correcto.
La librería en C++ es:
class CONFIG
{
public:
     
    class TAB
    {
    public:
        UCHAR   Voc;
    };

    class ZAN
    {
    public:
        UCHAR   RN;
        UCHAR   TN;
    };
};

class CTRL_CONFIG
{
public:
    UCHAR   Vng;    
};

y lo que he pasado a C# es:
public class SCFWrap
{
 

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public struct CONFIG
            {
                [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
                public struct TAB
                {
                    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
                    public  byte Voc;
                }

                [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
                public struct ZAN
                {
                    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
                    public  byte RN;
                    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
                    public  byte TN;
                }
        }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public struct CTRL_CONFIG
        {
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]  
            public byte Vng;
        }
}

Alguien podría decirme si la conversión que he hecho es correcta? Tenía otra librería hecha del mismo modo pero no sé que ocurre con esta
Gracias de antemano

El código se ve correcto. Podrías mostrar cómo lo estás usando?

debe haber algun output relacionado al error ... podrias mostrarlo???
